# Abort Trap Error: 6 - where is it coming from? - Sudoku solver

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, backtracking, sudoku

Have a sudoku solver method that check row/col location for solution and backtracks after testing if a number is not correct. It is printing out `No Solution` followed by `Abort Trap Error: 6`. I am using a test case that should return TRUE. Row and Col are initially being passed in parameter as 0

What might be the issue? I'm thinking it could be how I am incrementing row and col. It reads in a single line file and translates to 2D grid

Here is test input: 4.....8.5.3..........7......2.....6.....8.4......1.......6.3.7.5..2.....1.4......

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BLANK '.'
 #define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define BLANK_SPACE '.'



int findBlankSpace(int grid2D[9][9]);
 int valid(int grid2D[9][9], int rowIndex, int colIndex, int num);

 void prettyPrint(int grid2D[9][9]);
 int readLine(int grid2D[9][9]);
 int findSolution(int grid2D[9][9],int row, int col);
 int UsedInRow(int grid2D[9][9], int row, int num);
 int UsedInCol(int grid2D[9][9], int col, int num);
 int UsedInBox(int grid2D[9][9], int boxStartRow, int boxStartCol, int num);

int findSolution(int grid2D[9][9], int row, int col)
{

  row = 0;

  if (findBlankSpace(grid2D) == FALSE)
    return TRUE;

  if (row == 9) {
    row = 0;
  }

  for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++)
  {
    if (valid(grid2D, row, col, num))
    {
        grid2D[row][col] = num;

        if (findSolution(grid2D, row, ++col))
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    grid2D[row][col] = 0;
    row++;
   }
  return FALSE;
}

int findBlankSpace(int grid2D[9][9])
{
  int row;
  int col;
     for (row = 0; row < 9; row++)
       for (col = 0; col < 9; col++)
          if (grid2D[row][col] == 0)
            return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}
int UsedInRow(int grid2D[9][9], int row, int num)
{
for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
    if (grid2D[row][col] == num)
        return TRUE;
return FALSE;
}


 int UsedInCol(int grid2D[9][9], int col, int num)
{
   for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
      if (grid2D[row][col] == num)
          return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
 }

 int UsedInBox(int grid2D[9][9], int row1, int col1, int    num)
 {
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
      for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
          if (grid2D[row+row1][col+col1] == num)
              return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
   }

int valid(int grid2D[9][9], int row, int col, int num)
{
return !UsedInRow(grid2D, row, num) &&
       !UsedInCol(grid2D, col, num) &&
       !UsedInBox(grid2D, row - row % 3, col - col % 3, num); 

}

int readLine(int grid2D[9][9])
{
    int c;
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
       if(c == '.')
       {
           grid2D[row][col] = 0;
       } 
       else
       {
           grid2D[row][col] = c - '0';
           col++;
       }

       if(col%9 == 0)
       {
           row++;
           col = 0;
       }
  }

return 0;
 }
 void prettyPrint(int grid2D[9][9])
{
int count = 0;
int row;
int col;

printf("solution:\n");
/* Use nested for-loops to iterate through 2-D array */
for(row = 1; row <= 9; row++)
{
    for(col = 1; col<=9; col++)
    {
        /* After every 3rd character, print out "|", forming the board   */
        if((col%3==0)&&(col%9!=0))
        {
            printf("%d| ", grid2D[row - 1][col - 1]);
        }
        else
            printf("%d ", grid2D[row - 1][col - 1]);
        count++;
    }
    /* After every 3rd row, print out horizontal separations */
    if((row%3==0)&&(row!=9))
    {
        /* Advance to the next line prior to printing separation to give space */
        printf("\n");
        printf("------+-------+------");
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
}

int main()
{

   int grid2D[9][9];

   readLine(grid2D);

   if(findSolution(grid2D, 0, 0)==TRUE)
   {
    prettyPrint(grid2D);
   }
   else
   {
    printf("No Solution Found!\n");
   }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: @EugeneSh. I just added the main method. It just prints out the answer if `findSolution()` is true

Comment: Is it really printing "No Solution", or is it printing the whole printf statement "No Solution Found!\n"?

Comment: I am sure that if you had taken the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE], you might have tried stepping into your program with a debugger to identify where in the code the fault is coming from. Given that it probably happens on exit, you have likely trashed process memory somewhere.  That could easily have been in the one missing function `readLine`.

Comment: @JGroven, no it is printing `"No Solution Found!\n"`

Comment: I don't get `if (row == 9) { row = 0; }` Sudoku does not wrap.

Comment: Thanks @jwdonahue, I would use a debugger, but we have not learned that  yet in our course. I just added readLine. It reads in a single line input of numbers as the sudoku puzzle, ex: `4.....8.5.3..` etc

Comment: @WeatherVane, I was attempting to reset the row value after reaching 9 to progress down to the next column and restart at 0

Comment: We still don't have an MCVE.  The 'C' in MCVE stands for "Compilable".

Comment: So why does that not advance and test the next column? `if (row == 9) { row = 0; col++; if(col...)}`

Comment: You hand enter 81 numeric values?  What value string(s) cause the fault?

Comment: FWIW, the [previous version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919409) has better code than the current version of the question. Of course, that code was not [complete or verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) either, so it's hard to say if the missing pieces were correct.

Comment: @jwdonahue, sorry about that I just added the rest of the program and also added a test input

Comment: @user3386109 I just added the rest of the code for the program so it is compilable

Comment: @jwdonahue the test input is saved as a .in file, but I don't know how to upload a document

Comment: The `readline` function doesn't increment `col` when it sees a `.` And you should probably verify that you actually finished filling the grid, and didn't run past the end of the grid. In other words, make sure that you got exactly 81 characters. Wouldn't hurt to verify that the numbers are actually numbers.

Comment: On VS-2017 I get `Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'grid2D' was corrupted.`

Comment: Your input example is 82 characters long, not 91.

Comment: Debugging tip: Change `main` so that it calls `readline` and then does nothing except call `prettyPrint`. That allows you to verify that your input and output code is working, before adding the guts of the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks @jwdonahue, It looks like I included a space by accident when I was pasting the input example. It should be 81

Comment: Thanks @user3386109, I added your fix and also tested out the `pretty print()` like you were saying. It looks like the board is printing out correctly. The blank values are `0` and the rest are the provided values from input. The solve method is not working correctly

Comment: Yup, now you need to go back to the code you had in the previous question. Except don't use the `BLANK_SPACE` macro, since you're using `0` for a blank space, not `.`

Comment: Thanks @user3386109! looks like that fixed it . It only messed up on a few numbers, I will look into the rest

Comment: Cool, good luck!

Comment: rather than specifically defining `true` and `false`, strongly suggest adding the statement: `#include <stdbool.h>`  which already has everything defined for you.

Comment: the `readline()` function has not 'stop' logic, so it will keep on inputting (or hang while waiting for input) until the user presses (depending on the OS) <ctrl>-<z>  or <ctrl>-<d>

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 3, 9.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) to reduce the chance of introducing an error into the logic, suggest including the optional braces after `for()` and `if()` and `else` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the recursive function: findSolution(), eventually the 'col' parameter will be 9 (or greater)! When that happens, the code will be accessing outside the bounds of the current row in the array. This results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.